# Simple reverse and forward controller for a 24v dc motor?

Tags: relay

I have a project for my grand father and I would like to make a simple switch for his electric wheelchair. The controller of the wheelchair is already not working. Just a simple switching just to make it working. Specification: 2 motors 50A max 24vdc each. If I push the switch in forward the two motor will move in forwad motion and same in reverse mode. For turning right and left only one motor will move. If turning left only the left motor will move. Pls help me to this project it will help alot to my grand father. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a DC motor is simply switched on, it draws much more than the normal running current and develops a lot of torque in trying to get to full speed as quickly as possible. That is not going to work very well for a wheelchair. It is possible to control a DC motor to some extent with large resistors, but that is not really as simple as it sounds. I don't think there is any good alternative to the proper electronic controller.

Comment: Get a proper ESC (electronic speed controller), they are simple to work with, and you can get an 80A speed controller per motor. These are USD$38 each and would be perfect, for integration with a simple microcontroller or RC style interface http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__24254__Turnigy_AE_80A_Brushless_ESC.html

Comment: @KyranF - That unit is for a brushless DC motor, and is probably not usable by the OP.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast maybe, OP didn't specify what the motor type was.. either way, hopefully they can source something similar for their type of motor, and make use of the speed profiles or soft-start features

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your motors are brushed DC motors (2 wires), you can in fact do this. However, 50 amps is a LOT of current, and the parts are not cheap. Unless you are willing to spend ~$300 (minimum) I advise you to get the chair fixed.

Comment: I agree - fix the controller. Simply switching current to the motors (and 2400W is over 3 horsepower) is likely to propel grandfather violently out of the chair.